# Bootstrap .col woes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, col

I'm having trouble getting my bootstrap col's to behave how I want, I was wondering if someone could help as I'm still quite new to Bootsrap.

I'm aiming for the following:

```
for larger screens, i want to have it like this:
------------------------------------
|                        |     2    |
             1           ------------
|                        |     3    |
------------------------ |          |
                         ------------
```

-i.e 2 and 3 are independant of the height of 1, and stay in the same column even if 2 pushes 3 lower than the bottom of 1

```
For medium screens look tike this:
 -------------------------
|                        |
|           1            |
|                        |  
 ------------------------|         
|-----------|------------|
|      2    |     3      |
|-----------|------------|
```

-where 2 and 3 drop below 1 equally

```
And for smallest screens look like this!
 --------- 
|         |
|    1    |
|         |
 --------- 
|    2    |  
 --------- 
|    3    |  
 ---------
```

-all in a single column

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple Bootstap layout, but it's hard to say not seeing your code and not knowing the heights of the content.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/KaeCBJoXJW

Comment: Thankyou for your help! I think because my code within these div's is getting so complex i'm getting a bit confused haha. Just one last thing, is there a way to keep Box#3 in the diagrams above on the right hand side even when it has been pushed below Box#1 by a large content in Box#2? (on large screens) Thanks! :)